# String was not recognized as Valid Datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have 2 textboxes where I have to add the `Joining Date` and `Leaving Date`.

Now When I add the joining date and leave the `Leaving date` blank and submit the form I get error as

> String was not recognized as Valid Datetime

Here is my code for

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text);
```

I dont know why this is giving error. Please help

UPDATE:

Textbox code:-

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtdol" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddNew" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What code do you use in Textbox? its not valid format. if you input date by user to textbox, maybe he not input date in valid format.

Comment: @RashedDIP: Added the textbox code

Comment: Some time this error happen because of empty textbox or wrong format date . i give you sample now that can help you for your program.

Comment: @RashedDIP: Yes sure, give will check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting so much errors, Did like this

```
 if (txtdol.Text == null || txtdol.Text == string.Empty)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text);
                        }
```

And it worked..!!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you enter date in valid format in the textbox. best option is to use a date validator for the textbox and if the date formate entered is wrong you can display validation error rather than RTE.

here is the question for validation:

[Date validation for a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667199/date-validation-for-a-textbox)

here is the available date format from MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

of course you get error for that . the error happening in

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text);
```

you are trying to convert something that is null , its like you say to compiler to compile this :

```
Convert.ToDateTime("");
```

it's emptry string and cannot be converted .

here are some options that you can consider of :

1. Check if the textbox is not empty and the provided date is valid (client or server side)
2. use DateTimePicker (like jquery ui datetimepicker)
3. use this code instead of that at the end of that line

   String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdol.Text) ? DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text)

if txtdol is null or empty it return the current datetime otherwise it convert the txtdol to datetime and return it .

Answer (score 0):

Good way to input date to Textbox by user is using :
1- MaskedTextBox 
  or 
2- DateTimePicker.
Or 
  if you want using textbox, you can use this code also to check empty values.

```
 DateTime? nullDateTime = null;
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdol.Text.Trim()) ? nullDateTime : Convert.ToDateTime(txtdol.Text.Trim())
```

and for validation textbox check this function:

```
private bool validateDate(TextBox arg1)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            bool valid1 = DateTime.TryParseExact(arg1.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg1.Text.Trim()) )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Format Date is wrong! Currect format is(dd/MM/yyyy)", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                arg1.Focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Everytime it is taking the todays date as leaving date by default. why ?

Comment: Oh, maybe in definition of table in sql used default value. some time its occurred due to not match format date in C# with SQL server.

Comment: Checked Allow Null value in definition of field leavedate in SQL.

Comment: I think that checking null value can not be used for datetime null value.

Comment: Still you see today date only?

Answer (score 0):

This error occures due to Invalid date format (empty or wrong format) enterd in textbox to fix the issue modify the code as below , use DateTime.ParsExact

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@leaving_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParsExact(txtdol.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite);
```

the second paramater can be changed to an array of format also.

Change the code as per your need

Comment: Error: `The best overloaded method match for … has some invalid arguments” error`

Comment: Dear , please try this , DateTime.ParseExact(txtdol.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", (new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US",false)));

Comment: Still getting the error as `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: have you see my answer ? what about that ?